# Making table in PHP from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a database called clanovi (members in englsih) which has stored name, surname, adress, email and gender of members. What I am trying to do is make a table from this data from database.

Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/9j34xfwx/2/

```
<body>
<?php
require_once("Konekcija.php");  
error_reporting(0);

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("umv");

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clanovi ORDER BY rbroj ASC");

$ime='ime';
$prezime='prezime';
$adresa='adresa';
$email='email';
$spol='spol'; 
?>


<table id='display'>
<?php
while ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
?>

<tr><td>Ime clana:     <?php echo $rows[$ime]; ?></td>
<tr><td>Prezime clana: <?php echo $rows[$prezime]; ?></td>
<tr><td>Adresa clana:  <?php echo $rows[$adresa]; ?></td>
<tr><td>Email clana:   <?php echo $rows[$email]; ?></td>
 <tr><td>Spol clana:    <?php echo $rows[$spol]; ?></td>
 <?php  
 }
 ?>
 </table>
```

Here is photo of my web page when it lists all members 
from database http://pho.to/ACgD1

[image]

My question is, how can I make a table so members name, surname, adress, email and gender are in columns, and beneath are the data from database. As you can see on the photo, my code adds one member beneath another member.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix it and you're all set.

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions.  They're obsolete. Deprecated and removed from PHP7

Comment: btw, you've an encoding issue

Comment: Nice Fiddle :) I liked it, yummy!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't need to repeat the text like "Ime clana:" (say `label`) in each Iteration, and need to set it as column header instead, cause that's the exact problem that the HTML `<table>` is designed to solve. Also if you need the `label` data to be redundant, then you must be defeating the purpose of using a `table`, IMHO.

You need to do something like this..

```
<table id='display'>
 <tr>
  <th>Ime clana:</th>
  <th>Prezime clana:</th>
  <th>Adresa clana:</th>
  <th>Email clana:</th>
  <th>Spol clana:</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
 while ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $rows[$ime]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rows[$prezime]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rows[$adresa]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rows[$email]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $rows[$spol]; ?></td></tr>
 <?php  
 }
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! As you said I did not need to repeate the text "Ime clana:" , but I did not know how to change the code so it is as column header. Tnx for help, my problem is solved! :)

Comment: Glad that my suggestion helped! I am also baffled how everyone missed the purpose of (you) OP using a `table`, if you just wanted to output the `key => value`. None the less. Keep rocking!

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a new row for every value (and then never closing those rows, which the browser is attempting to correct for you):

```
<tr><td>Ime clana:     <?php echo $rows[$ime]; ?></td>
 ^--- here
```

Just create the row *once* for each iteration of the loop:

```
<tr>
    <td>Ime clana:     <?php echo $rows[$ime]; ?></td>
    etc.
</tr>
```

Comment: Baffled as to why your answer received a downvote. I upvoted btw.

Answer (score 0):

Use this It's work for you.

```html
<table id='display'>
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Ime clana:</th>
  <th>Prezime clana:</th>
  <th>Adresa clana:</th>
  <th>Email clana:</th>
  <th>Spol clana:</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <?php
   while ($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
 ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $rows[$ime]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows[$prezime]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows[$adresa]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows[$email]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $rows[$spol]; ?></td>
   </tr>
 <?php  
 }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.